# Integral sign in exponential is too small

Tags: symbols, inline

I have `e^{\int_t^{\bar t}2\lambda(s)ds}` and I want the integral sign to be somewhat larger. I've tried `\big`, `\large`,.. and none of these has any effect. I've rejected `\exp{\int_t^{\bar t}\lambda(s)ds}` for aesthetic reasons. Thanks.

Comment: I'd reject `e^{...}` for aesthetic reasons. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I guess that your formula has to be used in a display.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
e^{\mathop{\textstyle\int_{t}^{\bar{t}}}\lambda(s)\,ds}
\qquad
e^{\int_{t}^{\bar{t}}\lambda(s)\,ds}
\qquad
\exp\bigl({\textstyle\int_{t}^{\bar{t}}\lambda(s)\,ds}\bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

My preference would be in inverse order: 3, 2 and 1.

A possible refinement would be to use smaller style for the bounds in 1:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\eint}{e{_^}}{%
  \mathop{%
    \textstyle\int
      \IfValueT{#1}{_{\scriptscriptstyle#1}}%
      \IfValueT{#2}{^{\scriptscriptstyle#2}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\[
e^{\eint_{t}^{\bar{t}}\lambda(s)\,ds}
\qquad
e^{\int_{t}^{\bar{t}}\lambda(s)\,ds}
\qquad
\exp\bigl({\textstyle\int_{t}^{\bar{t}}\lambda(s)\,ds}\bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, my list of preferences doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\mathlarger` command, from `relize`, like this:

```
e^{\mathlarger{\int}_t^{\bar t}\!2\lambda(s)\,ds
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I settled on \textstyle, which I should have thought of on my own.